# EF Core How to filter a nested many-to-many list by another list

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Using .Net Core 2.1 and EF Core 2.1.4

I'm trying to grab all the nested records of an object if any of those records contains a name that I have in a list, and only objects that have matching nested records.

I have a query that is producing the right results, but it's performing a query for every single record in the database table.

I'm hoping to reduce it further, if possible.

My ViewModels (actual models are nearly identical):

**EventViewModel**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;

namespace MyProject.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class EventViewModel
    {
        private string _name;

        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(100)]
        public string Name
        {
            get => _name?.Trim();
            set => _name = value?.Trim();
        }

        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime Date { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Programs")]
        public IEnumerable<EventProgramViewModel> EventProgramViewModels { get; set; }

        public string AllProgramNames
        {
            get
            {
                string result = EventProgramViewModels.Aggregate(string.Empty,
                    (current, program) => current + $"{program?.ProgramViewModel?.Name}, ");
                return result.TrimEnd(',', ' ');
            }
        }

        public EventViewModel()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid();
            Date = DateTime.Now;
            EventProgramViewModels = new List<EventProgramViewModel>();
        }
    }
}
```

**EventProgramViewModel**

```
using System;

namespace MyProject.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class EventProgramViewModel
    {
        public Guid EventViewModelId { get; set; }
        public EventViewModel EventViewModel { get; set; }

        public Guid ProgramViewModelId { get; set; }
        public ProgramViewModel ProgramViewModel { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**ProgramViewModel**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace MyProject.Models.ViewModels
{
    public class ProgramViewModel
    {
        private string _name;

        public Guid Id { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(100)]
        [Display(Name = "Program Name")]
        public string Name
        {
            get => _name?.Trim();
            set => _name = value?.Trim();
        }
    }
}
```

In my **ApplicationDbContext.cs** file I have this mapped like so:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<EventProgram>()
            .HasKey(eventProgram => new {eventProgram.EventId, eventProgram.ProgramId});
```

Finally, here is my **query**:

```
var testQuery = context.Events
        .AsNoTracking()
        .Select(e => new EventViewModel
        {
            Id = e.Id,
            Name = e.Name,
            Date = e.Date,
            EventProgramViewModels = e.EventPrograms.Select(eventProgram =>
                new EventProgramViewModel
                {
                    ProgramViewModel = new ProgramViewModel
                    {
                        Name = eventProgram.Program.Name
                    }
                })
        })
        .OrderByDescending(eventViewModel => eventViewModel.Date)
        .ThenBy(eventViewModel => eventViewModel.Name)
        .Where(eventViewModel =>
            !search.ProgramsChosen.Any() || eventViewModel.EventProgramViewModels.Any(
                eventProgramViewModel =>
                    search.ProgramsChosen.Contains(eventProgramViewModel.ProgramViewModel
                        .Name)))
        .ToList()
    ;

foreach (var item in testQuery)
{
    // Mock usage to show where queries are generated
    _loggingServices.LogInformation(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item));
}
```

This produces one EF query for the main `Event` properties:

```sql
SELECT [e].[Id], [e].[Name], [e].[Date]
FROM [Events] AS [e]
ORDER BY [e].[Date] DESC, [e].[Name]
```

And 1 for *each* result (in this case, in the above `foreach` loop)

```sql
SELECT [eventProgram.Program].[Name]
FROM [EventPrograms] AS [eventProgram]
INNER JOIN [Programs] AS [eventProgram.Program] ON [eventProgram].[ProgramId] = [eventProgram.Program].[Id]
WHERE @_outer_Id = [eventProgram].[EventId]
```

**Is there any way I can improve this performance?**

---

**Update 1:**

Based on [TyCobb's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53306770/ef-core-how-to-filter-a-nested-many-to-many-list-by-another-list?noredirect=1#comment93494617_53306770) I changed the query structure to:

```
var testQuery =
        context.Events
            .AsNoTracking()
            .OrderByDescending(@event => @event.Date)
            .ThenBy(@event => @event.Name)
            .Where(@event =>
                !search.ProgramsChosen.Any() || @event.EventPrograms.Any(
                    eventProgramViewModel =>
                        search.ProgramsChosen.Contains(eventProgramViewModel.Program
                            .Name)))
            .Select(e => new EventViewModel
            {
                Id = e.Id,
                Name = e.Name,
                Date = e.Date,
                EventProgramViewModels = e.EventPrograms.Select(eventProgram =>
                    new EventProgramViewModel
                    {
                        ProgramViewModel = new ProgramViewModel
                        {
                            Name = eventProgram.Program.Name
                        }
                    })
            })
    ;
```

Which is better, as it only produces a query for each valid record, where before it would do every record regardless.

This now produces this one query:

```sql
SELECT [event].[Id], [event].[Name], [event].[Date]
FROM [Events] AS [event]
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [EventPrograms] AS [eventProgramViewModel]
    INNER JOIN [Programs] AS [eventProgramViewModel.Program] ON [eventProgramViewModel].[ProgramId] = [eventProgramViewModel.Program].[Id]
    WHERE [eventProgramViewModel.Program].[Name] IN (N'A SEARCHED PROGRAM NAME') AND ([event].[Id] = [eventProgramViewModel].[EventId]))
ORDER BY [event].[Date] DESC, [event].[Name]
```

And one for each valid record:

```sql
SELECT [eventProgram.Program].[Name]
FROM [EventPrograms] AS [eventProgram]
INNER JOIN [Programs] AS [eventProgram.Program] ON [eventProgram].[ProgramId] = [eventProgram.Program].[Id]
WHERE @_outer_Id = [eventProgram].[EventId]
```

Comment: Try to do all filtering/ordering before your `Select`. The way it currently is written, it needs to get everything and map it to your view model and then it will filter based on your view model's properties.You want to try and have your select be the last thing it does.

Comment: @TyCobb I've updated my question to reflect your suggested changes, it is definitely better, but I'm still producing a query for each valid record. I'll build my other queries with this tip in mind though, thank you!

Comment: Not too sure. It's being treated as lazy loaded even though you mapped to a non-entity. You could try turning lazy loading off if you have it on and also try to do an `Include(...)` for your events children that you are using.

Comment: Don't have Lazy Loading turned on, and the Include `is unnecessary and was ignored because the navigation is not reachable in the final query results`

Comment: @TyCobb I was able to figure it out. Adding `.ToList()` to `EventProgramsViewModels = ....Select(... => new EventProgramViewModel{ ... })` did the trick. I had tried it before, but got errors every time, but no longer after moving my `OrderyBy()` and `Where()` to the top of my query.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two issues.

The first (which you solved with the **Update 1**) is caused by the current EF Core query translation defect which causes client evaluation of the `Where` clause (the `OrderBy` is ok). So moving the filtering before the projection is the current way to workaround it.

The second is the so called `N + 1` subquery issue. EF Core 2.1 contains [Optimization of correlated subqueries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#optimization-of-correlated-subqueries), which works in your case, but as mentioned in the documentation, you are expected to opt-in for it by adding `ToList` (or `ToArray`):

> We have improved our query translation to avoid executing "N + 1" SQL queries in many common scenarios in which the usage of a navigation property in the projection leads to joining data from the root query with data from a correlated subquery. The optimization requires buffering the results from the subquery, and we require that you modify the query to opt-in the new behavior.

and then

> By including `ToList()` in the right place, you indicate that buffering is appropriate for the Orders, which enable the optimization

So the final query should be something like this:

```c#
var testQuery = context.Events
    //.AsNoTracking() <-- No need when using projection
    .OrderByDescending(@event => @event.Date)
    .ThenBy(@event => @event.Name)
    .Where(@event =>
        !search.ProgramsChosen.Any() || @event.EventPrograms.Any(
            eventProgram =>
                search.ProgramsChosen.Contains(eventProgram.Program
                    .Name)))
    .Select(e => new EventViewModel
    {
        Id = e.Id,
        Name = e.Name,
        Date = e.Date,
        EventProgramViewModels = e.EventPrograms.Select(eventProgram =>
            new EventProgramViewModel
            {
                ProgramViewModel = new ProgramViewModel
                {
                    Name = eventProgram.Program.Name
                }
            }).ToList() // <-- 
    })
    .ToList()
    ;
```

which will result in 2 SQL queries:

```sql
SELECT [event].[Id], [event].[Name], [event].[Date]
FROM [Events] AS [event]
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM [EventPrograms] AS [eventProgramViewModel]
    INNER JOIN [Programs] AS [eventProgramViewModel.Program] ON [eventProgramViewModel].[ProgramId] = [eventProgramViewModel.Program].[Id]
    WHERE [eventProgramViewModel.Program].[Name] IN (N'P2', N'P4', N'P7') AND ([event].[Id] = [eventProgramViewModel].[EventId]))
ORDER BY [event].[Date] DESC, [event].[Name], [event].[Id]
```

and

```sql
SELECT [t].[Date], [t].[Name], [t].[Id], [eventProgram.Program].[Name] AS [Name0], [event.EventPrograms].[EventId]
FROM [EventPrograms] AS [event.EventPrograms]
INNER JOIN [Programs] AS [eventProgram.Program] ON [event.EventPrograms].[ProgramId] = [eventProgram.Program].[Id]
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [event0].[Date], [event0].[Name], [event0].[Id]
    FROM [Events] AS [event0]
    WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [EventPrograms] AS [eventProgramViewModel0]
        INNER JOIN [Programs] AS [eventProgramViewModel.Program0] ON [eventProgramViewModel0].[ProgramId] = [eventProgramViewModel.Program0].[Id]
        WHERE [eventProgramViewModel.Program0].[Name] IN (N'P2', N'P4', N'P7') AND ([event0].[Id] = [eventProgramViewModel0].[EventId]))
) AS [t] ON [event.EventPrograms].[EventId] = [t].[Id]
ORDER BY [t].[Date] DESC, [t].[Name], [t].[Id]
```

Comment: That's exactly it! I just posted a comment a moment ago to TyCobb on my question how I came to same conclusion. Thanks for figuring it out, writing it up, and posting!

Comment: Yeah, I just saw you found it while I was writing the answer :)

Comment: Wow, good to know on the the whole `ToList` for subqueries. Currently still working with 6.2 and was expecting the subqueries to work the same.